# C++: Static and Dynamic libraries ( compiling and running)

Tags: c++, dll, static, compilation

I'm working on a library project which is pretty much finished. So I'm giving it a test run now. I have no problem running my test project. However I'm not entirely sure if I'm doing it right. Mainly because I don't really understand what is happening exactly( at least im not entirely sure).

I've compiled both the DLL and Static library(.a). For my test project i'm using the Headers from my library and linking against the static library. I'm able to compile. But then It seems that I also need the DLL where the executable resides in order for it to run.

So to my understanding, I compile using the static library but I don't exactly embed it into my executable, therefor at runtime it's looking for the DLL?

My confusion comes from the fact that I read that static libraries are usually embedded into the executable. But doesn't that only happen if you specify that in the compiler options?

I'm rather confused about the relationship in my sittuation. Can someone clarify this?

Edit:
I'm using GCC.
Codelite as my IDE.

Comment: You say dll, so I assume you're targeting windows.  Windows does it differently than anything else.  Is this your target platform or did I misassume?

Comment: @Wug
for now it is my target platform yes. But the library should also work in Linux ( still have to test it though). For now windows it is.

Comment: In Windows a static library is usually a .lib. What tools are you using? How are you creating the static library.

Comment: If you're linking against a .lib and still need a corresponding .dll, it seems that you're linking with a include lib - these don't actually contain code, but instead make static linking to DLLs very easy (at the obvious cost of requiring a 100% compatible DLL)

Comment: @AlanStokes I'm using gcc. Not VC. Like I said, It's a ".a" file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lib is static (cannot be dynamically linked at run time) at compile time. So you are correct that the lib is "embedded" in the executable. More precisely, the lib is linked to other object files that the compiler has produced to build the exe file. A lib cannot link to another lib, only an exe or a dll can link to a lib.

dll is dynamically linked by the exe while the exe is run. dll is like another exe, but its entry function is "dllmain" instead of "main". dll can be built with lib's just like exe. dll can also link to other dll's at runtime to interface with these dlls' functionalities. The interface to dll is defined by a def file.

As to why your project would need the dll, you might want to check the calls of LoadLibrary in your project.

Comment: Considering his description it's somewhat likely that he's linking against an import library (which also use the .lib extension)

Comment: But what is the point of linking to a lib if it's already embedded in the executable code? And I honestly have no idea how to check the LoadLibrary.
@MFH it's a ".a" file. But there shouldn't be much of a difference right?

Comment: @Sidar If I remember correctly .a is a default file extension on Unix for static libraries. As you said your're currently on Windows, I'd assume that the only difference here will be the file extension - that could be checked with dumpbin (if you have it on your system). In case that assumption holds true and that lib is simply an import library, it's quire obvious why you'd still require the DLL after linking to the lib.

Comment: @MFH
While I want it to keep it as is, I never specified any import/export macros. Is import the standard? Or is there some settings in my project template that came with the IDE?

Comment: @Sidar: The following is likely the Microsoft way (I can only guess that GCC does the same): If you build a DLL, you get as additional output a lib. If you link to this lib the dependencies to the DLL get resolved automatically and you won't have to use LoadLibrary - the DLL will be loaded at runtime though => must be present on startup of the program.

Comment: @MFH
Well I only get a DLL and have to build the .a lib separately. I'm probably doing something wrong.  I have to look into this I guess.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14150/discussion-between-mfh-and-sidar)